# How to insert an array of strings in javascript into a PostgreSQL array

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-postgres

I have an array of strings and I would like to insert it into a PostgreSQL array.
I use query.pool() for the query.
Here is my request but does not insert anything in the DB and I have no error message in the console.

Help me please ;))

```js
const myArray = [ "first1.png", "second2.png", "third.png" ];

pool.query(
    `INSERT INTO images(pic_name) VALUES($1)`,
    [myArray],
    (error, result) => {
        if (error) {
            res.status(400).json({ error });
        }
        res.status(200);
    },
);
```

Comment: it seems like an id duplicate error , because the id is an constant , if in your table `images` `id` is auto_increment , u can just query with `INSERT INTO images( pic_name) VALUES($1)` ,and let the database manage the id when data is insert

Comment: No, that's not the problem, but you're right.

Comment: Try removing the brackets around `myArray` in your query.  `myArray` is already defined as an array.